# Compare 2 fields from different files and only return matches regardless of order

Tags: text-processing

I have 2 files
File1.txt:

```
Column1    | Column2
username2  | timestamp
username1  | timestamp
username4  | timestamp
```

File2.txt:

```
Column1    | Column2
username1  | timestamp
username3  | timestamp
username2  | timestamp
```

I want to output where they have matching Column1 values into a new file just showing Column1 content. Those values in Column1 are not always in the same order between file1.txt and file2.txt and some entries will be missing from either file.

Output-File3.txt

Column1
 username1
 username2

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F ' *| *' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

The array `a` is filled with the content of the first file1 column. Only lines matching an entry array will be printed when next file is parsed.

Comment: Thanks Oliv, although that gave me everything; matches and differences.

Comment: One minor drawback: if userX appears in file1, and it appears *twice* in file2, you'll see *both* instances in the output. You might want: `$1 in a {print $1; delete a[$1]}` to only print the first one.

Comment: In my case, there are no duplicates.

Comment: @Don, if this is the best answer, accept it. Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Extract column 1 from both files, sort it, then find the duplicated lines:

```
cut -d" " -f1 File1.txt File2.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: Thats almost it I reckon. Although there are single spaces infront of the first column text and those are being missed. How would you incorporate that?

Comment: Then `cut` is the wrong tool. Stick with awk.

Comment: Could I use cut to remove the first space?

Comment: No, you'd use `sed 's/^[[:blank:]]\+//'` to remove leading whitespace. But at this point, stringing several commands together, you'd be better off with a single awk program.

Answer (score -2):

Just sort both files before comparing them

```
sort f1 > f1s
sort f2 > f2s
diff f1s f2s
```